# When did singing at work fall in and out of vogue in western civilization?

Tags: labour-history, music

As far as I can tell, virtually nobody persistently sings at work. Especially not as in a semi-formal group effort such as a barbershop quartet or a call-and -response sea shanty.

I was taught in primary school that hard laborers in the olden days sang together to keep up moral. When and where did this begin? And when and why did it stop?

Comment: I could imagine that the common singing is a method to synchronize a lot of workers doing similar work (e.g. scullers). After the introduction of machines, the work must be synchronized with different individual operations in a production line. Then you don't need the similar rhythm.

Comment: You were taught at school.... but did they, actually? Or is this a myth / romanticisation / generalization?

Comment: the invention of the radio may have something to do with it.

Comment: Perhaps when we migrated away from hard labor to knowledge work.  I shudder at the thought of my office typing to music.  The horror, the horror.....   More seriously, I have my doubts whether this actually ever happened in history. Citations would help.

Comment: I still sing! My coworkers are all philistines I tell you. No appreciation for music

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace - Behold then the horror of the [IBM 1937 Corporate Songbook](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/08/tripping-through-ibms-astonishingly-insane-1937-corporate-songbook/). The link says they were still doing this into the 1960's, but I was told anecdotally by a former employee something like this was still in use in the 1970's.

Comment: @DevSolar - Look up the history of the [Sea Shanty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_shanty#Emergence). Yes, it was A Thing. At least for some tasks.

Comment: @T.E.D.: That is a very specific environment; the OP makes it sound as a rather general habit.

Comment: @DevSolar - That's not how I read it. Looks to me like its talking specifically about "hard laborers". "Nobody" doing it anymore certainly encompasses everyone, but that includes the "hard laborers" the question is asking about.

Answer (score 1):

Mechanization.

Work songs are a method to regulate joint or several labour. In joint labour it allows all labourers to pull together. In both joint and several labour it allows the labourers to regulate their pace of labouring and thus their exertion and exploitation.

In contrast mechanisation is used by capitalists to smash existing labour regulations (Thompson, “Time…” *Past & Present* [futon: libcom.org]). This allows capital to regulate labour by the pace of the machine. Even when workers sing to attack machine labour, their songs are not as fast as the real machine:

> Poverty poverty knock/
>   My loom is a saying all day

Versus a power loom’s cacophonous rapidity: https://youtu.be/-T2vrJ6haK0 at 1 minute plus